# Wakanda server start JSON error unexpected EOF

Tags: json, wakanda

WAK 1.1.3 - during solution load, get a backend error:

[Backend] Error
[Backend] SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected EOF

But it is not clear what file has this issue.  How to most efficiently isolate this?  I see nothing in the logs.  The application has been running stably.  I assume this is in a method, but am not finding it after a thorough search.

Thanks for guidance.

Kirk

Answer (score 2):

Unexpected EOF error could be as small as forgetting to close function body with a right curly bracket.

I recommend first checking all the code on the backend you have modified since the last successful restart.

Secondly, since this occurs during solution load, the error is likely in bootstrap code including login listener. Or in  model.js. You could try comment out all code in bootstrap.js or model.js see if the solution can load.